# Paypal recurring subscription payment, but with credits

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-adaptive-payments, recurring-billing

I've got a website that I'd like to set up a subscription-based access to. I really like the idea of using Paypal Express Checkout to do this, so that I have no responsibility of storing my customers' sensitive billing information myself, nor with doing the actual billing each month.

However...

I'd also like to reward a customer with one month's free subscription if they refer another customer to me. For instance, if you refer a new customer to me on September 10th, you don't get billed in October (you've already paid for all of September). If you refer three to me on September 10th, you don't a monthly charge again until January.

My understanding of the recurring payments via Express Checkout is that if I cancel the subscription for October, the customer is going to receive an email saying that the subscription was canceled, and then when I reenable it in November, they will also get an email from Paypal. Can I even re-enable the subscription without the customer agreeing to it?

What Paypal billing solution will best fit my needs? Am I going to have to store all my clients' billing information and send individual auth and capture requests each month? Is there a recurring payment setup that allows frequent cancelations and uncancelations? Should I let the regular recurring payment happen and then credit the account back?

It all seems quite awkward, but I'm new to this so there might be something I'm missing. Any help or advice would be most appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: You can't re-enable the subscription without the customer agreeing to. It would be like stealing the customer without his acknowledgement.